# Create NotesSession with Admin Account using c# Interop.domino.dll

Tags: c#, session, lotus-notes

How to create NotesSession with admin account using c# Interop.Domino.dll ? I don't want to get current session of notes client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [InitializeUsingNotesUserName](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_INITIALIZEUSINGNOTESUSERNAME_METHOD_SESSION_COM.html) method in the [NotesSession](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html) class, but it is only available if your C# code is running on a Domino server. If you are running in a client environment, you will have to switch the ID. You can do this by calling SECKFMSwitchToIDFile in the Notes C API, but you'll be getting into some pretty complex territory if you do this, and it might (I don't recall) change the KeyFileName entry in the Notes.ini file.